# Zope 2: Using manage_addProduct with own products (AttributeError)

Tags: zope

I'm a newbie to the Zope 2 programming world.  So please bear with me if I'm asking something obvious.

I created a sample product.  All is fine in ZMI: I can easily add/remove the product and change its attributes.  However I can't add the product in code or using the Zope debug mode.  I have read OFS.Folder code (as a reference) over and over again to find any differences to no avail.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could give me a hint/clue.  TIA,

The product code:

```py
##
## bahmanm.devistan.implementation.Devistan
##
from bahmanm.devistan.interfaces import IDevistan
from zope.interface import implements
from OFS.Folder import Folder
from Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplateFile import PageTemplateFile
from Acquisition import Implicit
from Globals import Persistent, InitializeClass
from AccessControl.Role import RoleManager
from OFS.ObjectManager import ObjectManager
from OFS.PropertyManager import PropertyManager
from OFS.FindSupport import FindSupport


class Devistan(Implicit, Persistent, RoleManager, Folder):
    """Devistan product implementation.
    """
    implements(IDevistan)
    meta_type = 'Devistan Site'
    _properties = ({'id': 'title', 'type': 'string', 'mode': 'wd'},)
    manage_options = (
        ObjectManager.manage_options +
        ({'label': 'View', 'action': ''}, ) +
        PropertyManager.manage_options +
        RoleManager.manage_options +
        Folder.manage_options +
        FindSupport.manage_options
        )
    index_html = PageTemplateFile(
        '../template/devistan/index.pt', globals())

    def __init__(self, id=None):
        if id is not None:
            self.id = str(id)

InitializeClass(Devistan)


manage_addDevistanForm = PageTemplateFile(
    '../template/devistan/manage_addDevistanForm.pt', globals())


def manage_addDevistan(self, id, title='', REQUEST=None):
    """Adds a new Devistan instance.
    """
    obj = Devistan(id)
    obj.title = title
    self._setObject(id, obj)
    if REQUEST is not None:
        return self.manage_main(self, REQUEST, update_menu=1)
    return "<p>Devistan instance successfully installed: <tt>%s</tt>" % id


def initialize(self):
    self.registerClass(
        Devistan,
        constructors=(manage_addDevistanForm,
                      manage_addDevistan))
```

`__init__.py` code:

```py
##
## bahman.devistan.__init__.py
##
from bahmanm.devistan.implementation import Devistan


def initialize(self):
    """Registers Devistan product.
    """
    Devistan.initialize(self)
```

The stacktrace when calling `manage_addDevistan` from a sample page:

```
2013-01-07 15:43:11 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1357560791.840.323411816939 http://localhost:8080/devistan/addSampleSite
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module bahmanm.devistan.implementation.Devistan, line 37, in addSampleSite
```

The output in Zope's debug mode:

```
>>> app.manage_addProduct['Devistan'].manage_addDevistan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: manage_addDevistan
```

buildout.cfg:

```
[buildout]
parts = zope2
        instance
extends = http://download.zope.org/Zope2/index/2.13.19/versions.cfg
develop = /home/bahman/Work/devistan/bahmanm.devistan

[zope2]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = Zope2
       bahmanm.devistan
interpreter = zopepy
debug-mode = on

[instance]
debug-mode = on
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
user = admin:admin
http-address = 8080
eggs = ${zope2:eggs}
zcml = bahmanm.devistan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add your product, just import the `manage_addDevistan` function directly:

```
from bahmanm.devistan.implementation import manage_addDevistan

manage_addDevistan(somefolder, 'someid')
```

Comment: My `configure.zcml` already included the content you mentioned.  And my package is listed in `parts/instance/etc/package-includes/`.

Does this mean that I have to rename the outer namespace to `Products`?

Comment: @BahmanM.: No; but you may want to verify (with a log statement) that the initialize function is being invoked.

Comment: Logging with `zLOG.LOG('DEVISTAN_LOG', 2, 'Initialize has been called', '')` shows no output in console.  I also tried putting `exit(-1)` inside `initialize` with no luck --though not sure if Zope allows calling `exit` at all.

Comment: @BahmanM.: It certainly allows calling `sys.exit`; for logging use the `logging` module from Python (`zLOG` is just an alias these days). I was barking up the wrong tree though, see my altered answer.